# Django - Use TextInput form to look up a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to build an application in Django where users should be able to create new entries for a model. Said model contains a ForeignKey relation to a different model. However, the classic dropdown form field is not practical, because there could be hundreds of entries to choose from. Instead, I'd like to allow users to simply type in the name of the entry (all names are unique), which then gets transformed to the corresponding ID when pressing the Submit button.

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward to do, but since I'm new to Django I'm having a hard time to figure out how to do it. Currently the problem is, that the form field is declared invalid, due to the ForeignKey not existing (since the user typed in the name and not the ID of the database entry).

Code example:

`forms.py`:

```
class DogForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Dog
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {" shelter": widgets.TextInput(attrs={"id":" shelter", "placeholder":" Dog Shelter"}),
        "name": widgets.TextInput({"id":"name", "placeholder":"Name"}),

def clean(self):
        
        shelter= self.data.get("shelter")
        self.cleaned_data["shelter"] = Shelter.objects.get(name=shelter)
        return self.cleaned_data
```

`views.py`:

```
class DogCreate(CreateView):
    model = Dog
    form_class = DogForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.save()
            return super(DogCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

As you can see, my idea was to overwrite the `clean` method, by adding the correct `Shelter` to `self.cleaned_data` (based on the name the user put into the TextInputField). But this does not seem to work, because when pressing submit, the form is still declared invalid.

Comment: There are packages out there that provide you an autocomplete like select. Check https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/ and see if any of the packages suit you.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Ended up using django-autocomplete-light.